# Provide value for self when using Proc#call

Tags: ruby

When using Proc#call to call a lambda function in Ruby, `self` always ends up with the value that it had when the function was defined, rather than the value it has when the function is called, for example:

```
$p = lambda { self }

class Dummy
  def test
    $p.call
  end
end

d = Dummy.new

> d.test
=> main
```

Calling `test` returns `main`, when what I intended it to return is `#<Dummy:0xf794>` - an instance of `Dummy`, which was the value of `self` at the point in the code where I called `$p`.

In Javascript, I would just pass the object that I want to be the "callee" as the first argument to `call`. Is there any such functionality in Ruby, allowing me to set an arbitrary object, or at least the current value of `self`, as the new value for `self` when  I call a `Proc`?

Comment: I had thought that `$p.bind(some_object)` might work, but apparently `bind` only operates with an `UnboundMethod` object.  Can a proc be coerced into an unboundMethod?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're looking for instance_eval, which evaluates a lambda in the context of the calling object.

```
>> $p = proc { self }
=> #<Proc:0x95cece4@(irb):1 (lambda)>
>> class Dummy
>>   def test
>>     $p.call
>>   end
>> 
>>   def test1
>>     instance_eval(&$p)
>>   end
>> end

>> d = Dummy.new
=> #<Dummy:0x946f7c8>
>> d.test
=> main
>> d.test1
=> #<Dummy:0x946f7c8>
```

Comment: When I try to send a block to `instance_eval` in this fashion, I always get the error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`.  I think @shwoodard's answer is now the correct answer.

Comment: Using a `proc` rather than a `lamda` should resolve the `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` exception.

Comment: Any explanation as of why `instance_eval { $p.call }` returns main, but `instance_eval(&$p)` returns the instance?

Answer (score 23):

You may want to use instance_exec because it allows you to pass arguments to the block whereas instance_eval does not.

```
def eval_my_proc_with_args(*args, &block)
  instance_exec(*args, &block)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

lambda defines a closure which means it will encapsulate the environment it had when it was defined.  If you want self to be the caller just define a regular method or better yet use a block.

Comment: Thanks - I know that lambda creates a closure, and I'd like to retain access to the encapsulated environment, but just override the one special variable `self`. Do you have any ideas on how I could do this?